# Error while trying to run a project on Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm just a beginner and I ran into a problem when launching the project's frontend.

When I running the following command:

```
npm run dev
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> > cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --mode=development --progress --port 8081 --open
>
> module.js:550
>    throw err;
>    ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'
> ...
> ```

The full error is shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUW14.png)

**package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "absolutum",
  "description": "My webpack project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Roman Tayursky <tayursky@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --mode=development --progress --port 8081 --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production -p --progress",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "~7.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mango-dct": "^1.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-drag-drop": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-input-mask": "0.0.11",
    "vue-masked-input": "^0.5.2",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "webpack-sources": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "~7.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "~7.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "~7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "~7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "~7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "element-ui": "^2.10.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "~1.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-cli": "^2.9.6",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6",
    "webpack": "^4.35.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-serve": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Help me please.

Comment: Try run `npm i` then run project again

Comment: I already did npm i, + wrote to the developer of this project, but he doesn't know how to help me start it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have just downloaded the project and trying to run,

before running you need to install dependencies listed in package.json of the project

to install use (make sure you are in the root path i.e where your package.json is present)

```
npm install
```

and then run

Comment: Hi r7r, I did in this sequence npm i, then npm run dev, tried tried to delete node_modules, but it didn't help( I wrote to the developer of this project, but he doesn't know how to help me so I'm on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If someone will be useful, then I'm in package.json removed / commented out vue-loader and installed it manually via npm i vue-loader. in my case, I also needed to install axios.All thanks:)